# Java - avoiding NonSuchElementException using ConcurrentLinkedDeque

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety

Building a multi thread program i ran into a problem:
the ConcurrentLinkedDeque's remove method was called by two threads and threw an exception. i can fix the problem by sync this method the way i did in this code, but i'm looking for a solution without synchronization.
I searched for other suitable structures but havn't find any that doesn't throw exception or wait for the queue to be filled again.

```
    public void releaseVehicle(DeliveryVehicle vehicle) {
    acquireTable.put(vehicle.getLicense(), true);
    synchronized (futureQueue) {
        if (!futureQueue.isEmpty())
            futureQueue.remove().resolve(vehicle);    

    }
}
```

i'm curious, is there another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `poll` instead. Since `ConcurrentLinkedDeque` doesn't allow `null` elements, `poll` returning `null` means the deque is empty (at the time of calling).

```
SomeClass element;
while ((element = deque.poll()) != null) {
    // do something with element
}
```